# sources of Testing Support Library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source, android-testing

How to attach sources from `android.support.test.*` for debugging in AS? 
Tried downloading sources from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing but the version doesn't seem to match my testing library version.

Testing sources (for instance `AndroidJunitRunner`) don't seem to be available via sdk manager, am I missing something ?

Comment: Just FYI: The source is not on master branch, you need to use the branch "android-support-test" and go back by tags (android-tsl-2.0, android-tsl-3.0, etc)...

Comment: @Yenchi interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem and it took a quite amount of time to figure it out. It seems like a bug due to a missing Gradle task not executed because the SAME configuration used to work but not any more after upgrading to AS v1.2+.

First, the following dependency is obsolete.

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
```

And it is updated as follows in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html).

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.2'
...
```

The defaultConfig should include the following line as usual.

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Also, make sure the Android Support Repository is installed through the SDK Manager.

If android.support.test.* cannot be resolved, then manually execute the Gradle task as follows.

1. Click the Gradle tab on the right.
2. Collapse your Android module and brow the Tasks node.
3. Double click to execute other->generateDebugAndroidTestSources

If succeeded, the issue may be solved. At least, it works for me.

**UPDATE:**

It seems like there are still chances this could happen on AS 2.1.2. To be noted, if you have more than one Android modules, running the gradle task `generateDebugAndroidTestSources` from one particular should be enough for all, especially the Android library module one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however, still no sources. I don't have `generateDebugAndroidTestSources` in my app Task-> others, only `generateDebugTestSources`. Where are the generated sources supposed to be located ?

Comment: Anyways, updgrading to AS 1.2 was a great idea, they seem to have default decompiler, which helps to get and idea of what's going on during debugging, thanks a lot!

Comment: It's probably means your app is not an Android module or the test sources are not under src/androidTest/java. Make sure you follow the convention and the Android support repository is really downloaded in your Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/.

Comment: well, the app is definitely android module :) and it does follow the convetions. And guess what, I just "manually" looked at `Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/` and found sources correctly downloaded there (in jars). I guess AS wasn't just picking it up properly.

Comment: do you know where to get matching sources of `junit` classes, such as `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` (matching version) used by `android.support.test.runner` (sources of which I now have thanks to you). Do I have to download them manually or is there similar way ?

Comment: If that is the case, we may not encounter exactly the same problem. I've updated to the latest version 1.3 preview. You may try to download the official android testing code at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing. Open the project in AS should expose the problem and run the Gradle task generateDebugAndroidTestSources is likely to fix it.
BTW, it seems like BlockJUnit4ClassRunner is part of junit which you may need to add dependency on respectively.

Comment: I am on Android 2.0 beta and run into same situation. Struggling to resolve this issue since yesterday, finally running 'generateDebugAndroidTestSources' solved the issue. Thanks @Farley

Answer (score 5):

I suffered this problem recently and I solve it now.
After I add the following dependencies and `Sync Project with Gradle file`, I can not find any relative library in the `External Library` folder.

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
```

What I do is to replace all `androidTestCompile` to `compile` and `Sync Project with Gradle file`. and I can see the relative libraries.

Last, I replace `compile` back to `androidTestCompile` and `Sync Project with Gradle file` again. The relative libraries are still there.

I want to post images to make it more clearly, but I am new in here and can not post images.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: changing 'androidTestCompile'  to 'compile' and syncing worked for me but changing back to 'androidTestCompile' gave me same problem..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Espresso for UI-tests and Robolectric + JUnit + Mockito for unit-tests.

Use AndroidJunitRunner, add it to build.gradle like:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

Use some package android.support.test.* you need add dependencies like

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}
```

Comment: I have all my dependencies setup. What I need is to attach source of what is declared as : `com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1` in your example

Comment: I add dependencies and my Gradle downloads jar or arr files. Use google to get the source code manual.