# Android Espresso testing 'Cannot resolve symbol 'InstrumentationRegistry''

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-espresso

I'm trying to import

```
 import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
```

my build.gradle file

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

in default config:

```
defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Is there a library I'm missing here? I'm trying to import InstrumentationRegistry but it doesn't recognise it!

Comment: please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373074/sources-of-testing-support-library-in-android-studio . Hope this helps .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yeah I've already tried that doesn't work.

Comment: did you see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869832/android-studio-project-setup-for-espresso-tests

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Check what kind of test do you use.

InstrumentationRegistry used for *Instrumented tests* 
that use emulator or device and they are placed in src/androidTest and use config **androidTestCompile**.
If you use *Local unit tests* for JVM from folder src/test you should use
config **testCompile**

```
testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```

After that you can import InstrumentationRegistry, but you will get other errors at run-time.

Comment: Agree, great answer! God bless you!) I've changed androidTestCompile to testCompile and InstrumentationRegistry resolved,

Answer (score 5):

try

**compile** 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'

instead of

testCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks

Comment: Use `implementation` as `compile` is obsolete

Answer (score 1):

it seems, `com.android.support.test` had been recently excluded from some other package (no clue which one), which also resulted in `android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry`to be unknown; not excluding it from `com.android.support.test:runner` fixed the issue for me.

```
androidTestImplementation ("com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2") {
    // exclude group: "com.android.support.test"
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```

basically, `androidTestImplementation` needs to contain `com.android.support.test` once.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative - you can also add `androidx.test:monitor` dependency where the class `InstrumentedRegistry` is.

`androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:monitor:x.y.z'`